# Maven won't run JUnit5 tests

Tags: java, maven, junit5

(BTW: Yes, I am including the Maven surefire plugin in my pom.)

I can't persuade Maven to run my JUnit5 tests.

- I am using the Maven surefire plugin version 2.22
- I tried downgrading the surefire plugin to 2.19
- I'm using the same dependencies and plugins as another project which runs fine
- If I import the project into eclipse, eclipse finds and executes the tests
- The class file for the test, app.AppTest.class, is in directory target\test-classes\app
- I don't get any error messages from Maven; it just says "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0"

I am including the contents of my pom, below. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uw.syp.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>Temp1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>01</version>
  <name>Temp1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
       <developer>JesseJW</developer>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:-serial</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>          
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As requested: source code including imports:
    package app;

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class AppTest
{
    void test()
    {
        System.out.println( "*************" );
        URL resURL  =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "ResFile.txt" );
        System.out.println( resURL );
        assertNotNull( resURL );
        if ( resURL != null )
        {
            System.out.println( resURL.getPath() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your test code including imports.

Comment: @ johanneslink Not very experienced at this. I submitted an edit and got "It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members "

Comment: Is this really your code? Where do you use your @Test annotation?

Comment: @Olimpiu POP Shoot. And I don't really mean "shoot." I've been troubleshooting an altogether different problem all day long, and I have a variety of Temp? directories and I have gotten them thoroughly confused. When I execute mvn test in the correct directory Maven finds the test just fine. Color me thoroughly embarrassed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @johanneslink You called it. I had my directories mixed up.

Comment: @JackStraub - yes, that is the way how it usually happens. The most naive part you leave behind. It's good to have rubber duckies now and then :). Should I post a response so that we can close the loop?

Comment: @Olimpiu POP, yes, please post a response. And thanks for being so kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you missed the annotation on your test methods. Just adapt your code to:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class AppTest
{
    @Test
    void test()
    {
        System.out.println( "*************" );
        URL resURL  =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "ResFile.txt" );
        System.out.println( resURL );
        assertNotNull( resURL );
        if ( resURL != null )
        {
            System.out.println( resURL.getPath() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code imports wrong `Test` annotation; `org.junit.Test`, `org.testng.annotations.Test`, ...

`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` should be imported.

```
package app;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class AppTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Parameters used by Surefire plugin (since 2.2) and worth double checking taking into account the project directory structure:

testSourceDirectory: the test source directory containing test class sources.
Default value is: ${project.build.testSourceDirectory} (default: src/test/java).

classesDirectory (for generated classes being tested).
Default value is: ${project.build.outputDirectory} (default: target/classes folder).

To change the defaults in pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

->

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/myPath</testSourceDirectory>
```

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Comment: does not make sense cause the post is using a much more recent version. apart from that the directories are default which means no need to define that.